# how to make a bump texture in blender?

Tags: texturing

i dont know what's it called in the CG world so here's a screenshot from payday 2 AK-47. it's really just a texture, not an actual holes and bolts.

[image]

how do you make those in blender ?

Comment: They are called Rivets. Take a circle and extrude and scale it . . .

Comment: To create such effects with texture only you may want to use normal maps (2 equal meshes + UV mapping etc should be done). For that you still should model all those details first and only then bake a normal map

Comment: I suggest to look some tutorial about normal maps baking, like this one: http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/585-normal-baking-using-the-blender-internal-renderer.html or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7PQGgz1RII

Comment: i actually know how to model those, but i just want to keep my model's poly to be as low as possible because i'm using subsurf modifier level 2. thanks for your suggestions btw.

Answer (score 4):

To fake relief on a surface you use a **bump map**, where the bright parts of the images will look as if they are sticking out of the surface.

For example in cycles. This plane with only 4 vertex shows fake relief.
[image]

Keep in mind that this is just a texture and if you look at it from the side it reveals the lack of height or real geometry.

[image]

For Blender internal the important setting is setting the **normal** as influence for the texture's image.

[image]

Comment: Is there a video tutorial on how you can achieve this?