# How to give UV mapped textures normal maps?

Tags: texturing, uv

Whenever I apply UV textures to a mesh, the texture looks flat after I rendered it. How to give it normal or bump maps? im doing animations cinematics not a game.

Comment: are you using blender internal or cycles?

Comment: internal renderer.

Comment: You need to use a bw version of your colour texture and use it to drive the bump map value in the texture slot. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/how-to-make-this-kind-of-texture-in-blender/33785#33785