# Blender Paint Texture

Tags: texturing, weight-painting, sculpting

[image: Texture]Hey, Guys. What i need to know in blender to made texture like that using prefer blender, red area. That game doesn't have normal maps. Fbx-model and Tga-texture

[image]
That is default game texture without normal map, i want make textures using blender and make like that relief from p90 mastery marked red. what i need to know in blender. Export tga

Comment: maybe related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/how-to-make-a-bump-texture-in-blender/33785#33785

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to create bump maps and normal maps?

Comment: i just need to know how to create that relief using blender tools that i marked as red, the game doesn't require normal map, only color texture