# Best way to approach dents?

Tags: texturing, materials

I was wondering what the best approach might be to replicate the dents found in the following picture?

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use a texture as bump map https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33756/how-to-make-a-bump-texture-in-blender

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a *Noise Texture* node (or another one) plugged into a *Bump* map. To get the crater effect you need to put a *ColorRamp* between the *Noise* and the *Bump*, and tweak the black and the white needles.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!